# Query giving undesirable results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two tables:

```
lab_assistant
la_id - la_firstname - la_lastname
1 - Dennis - Rodman
2 - Michael - Jordan
3 - Horace - Grant

hours_worked
hw_semester - hw_date - hw_hours - la_id
Fall 2012 - 2012-11-01 - 4 - 2
Fall 2012 - 2012-11-04 - 5 - 3
Spring 2012 - 2012-02-12 - 4 - 1
Spring 2012 -2012-03-10 - 4 - 1
```

The result of my query is supposed to look like the following:

and I'm trying to run the following query in order to list the Lab Assistant and the number of hours they worked each semester

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CONCAT(la.la_firstname, ' ', la.la_lastname)) AS 'Lab Assistant',
   hw.hw_semester AS 'Semester Worked', hw.hw_hours AS 'Hours Worked'
FROM lab_assistant la
    JOIN hours_worked hw
        ON la.la_id = hw.la_id;
```

The results of my quere are SUPPOSED to look like this:

```
Michael Jordan - Fall 2012 - 4
Horace Grant - Spring 2012 - 5
Dennis Rodman - Fall 2012 - 8
```

BUT the results I'm getting are as follows:

```
Michael Jordan - Fall 2012 - 4
Horace Grant - Fall 2012 - 5
Dennis Rodman - Spring 2012 - 4
```

So basically, it just isn't counting the proper hours for Dennis Rodman. It should be 8 and not 4.

And I probably shouldn't use DISTINCT here because it's possible the same person could work different semesters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DISTINCT` needs to go at the beginning of the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(la.la_firstname, ' ', la.la_lastname) AS 'Lab Assistant',
    hw.hw_semester, COUNT(w.hw_hours)
FROM lab_assistant la
    JOIN hours_worked hw
        ON la.la_id = hw.la_id;
```

But since you are using aggregate functions, you will want to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(la.la_firstname, ' ', la.la_lastname) AS 'Lab Assistant',
    hw.hw_semester, COUNT(w.hw_hours)
FROM lab_assistant la
    JOIN hours_worked hw
        ON la.la_id = hw.la_id
GROUP BY hw.hw_semester;
```

Based on your edit, you need something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(la.la_firstname, ' ', la.la_lastname) AS 'Lab Assistant',
  hw.hw_semester AS 'Semester Worked', 
  sum(hw.hw_hours) AS 'Hours Worked'
FROM lab_assistant la
JOIN hours_worked hw
  ON la.la_id = hw.la_id
GROUP BY la.la_id, hw.hw_semester;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/425a9/4)

Results:

```
|  LAB ASSISTANT | SEMESTER WORKED | HOURS WORKED |
---------------------------------------------------
|  Dennis Rodman |     Spring 2012 |            8 |
| Michael Jordan |       Fall 2012 |            4 |
|   Horace Grant |       Fall 2012 |            5 |
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `DISTINCT` is a modifier to `SELECT` and cannot be used like that. What's best in your case is to apply a `GROUP BY` on `hw.hw_semester` to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The [MySQL syntax for `SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) shows that `DISTINCT` needs to come before the column names:

```
SELECT
[ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
  [ .. etc .. ]
select_expr [, select_expr ...]
```

> Each **select_expr** indicates a column that you want to retrieve.

Basically, `DISTINCT` can only apply to the entire query, not a single column.